# "availability" not showing in Google Rich Snippet

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I’m using Schema.org properties to provide product data of my webshop to search engines. It includes stuff like the image, product name and price. All works great, and as a result, the price shows up nicely in Google’s search results.

However, the availability (In stock) for some reason doesn’t make it into the results, even after waiting a few weeks.

My products are on number 1 in the SERPs, just without the availability. I validated my page with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool and it looks great.

Does anyone know why Google doesn’t bother to show the availability?

A snippet of my source:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img itemprop="image" src="/media/product.jpg" alt="Product image">        
    <h2 itemprop="name">Product name</h2>

    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR">
        <span itemprop="price">€ 12,95</span>

       <ul>
            <li itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">Op voorraad</li>
        </ul>

    </div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know if this is the reason why Google Search does not pick it up, but your markup is not valid.

The `li` element can’t have a `href` attribute.

So instead of this

```html
<li itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">Op voorraad</li>
```

you should use, for example, this

```html
<li><link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>Op voorraad</li>
```

#### Side note: About your `price`

The value of the `price` property should not contain the currency symbol, so you might want to use this instead:

```html
<span itemprop="price">12,95</span> €
```

As Schema.org recommends to use the `.` as decimal separator, you could use the `data` element or the `meta` element to still how `,` to your visitors:

```html
<data itemprop="price" value="12.95">12,95</data> €
```

```html
<span><meta itemprop="price" content="12.95" />12,95</span> €
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes you suggested and notice a difference. When running it through the Structured Data Testing Tool, it now shows http://schema.org/InStock as value for availability. This used to be Op Voorraad (Dutch for In Stock). Let's hope this will affect the SERP.

Comment: A week later and now I can see Google showing the availibility in SERP for my products.

Answer (score 0):

The http://schema.org/InStock should idealy be defined at the itemscope level and your itemprop can continue to be mentioned in the li tag as before, without the link in it.

Google may not choose to show availability in organic search results depending on how relevant it perceives that information to be for users compared to price, item name etc (remember, there's only a limited amount of space in the results).

Do any of your other competitors' listings show availability?

Comment: Yes, some competitors with similar prices or higher rank lower in Google but does have their avaiilability shown.

Comment: Try rectifying your schema declarations as suggested in my answer, give it a few weeks and see if Google then starts including availability in your results as well.